# How to use an element belonging to an if-else cycle outside the cycle?

Tags: java, variables, arguments, if-statement

I need to use the variable of an if-else loop as an argument of a method or lets say somewhere out of the if-else loop but in the same class.

```
     public static String myvar;

                if(x > 5) {
                    myvar = 0 ;
                    Double  y = Double.parseDouble(myvar);
                    System.out.println("The value is: "+ y); }
                else
                {

                  Double  y= Double.parseDouble(myvar);
                  System.out.println("The value is: "+ y);
                }
```

So whenever i use the variable y somewhere out of the loop, it can not be resolved to a variable..How to use this variable out of the if-else loop?

Comment: if-else loop? There is no loop, only a branch.

Comment: All variables in Java belong to a **scope**. Usually designated by curly brackets. "y" is no longer "in scope" when that curly bracket closes. Google search for "Java scope" for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize the `y` variable out of the if-else loop.

Also your statement `myvar = 0;` will not compile as `myvar` is a String.

```
String myvar = "0";
Double y = 0.0;

if(x > 5) {
  y = Double.parseDouble(myvar);
  System.out.println("The value is: "+ y);
} else {
  y= Double.parseDouble(myvar);
  System.out.println("The value is: "+ y);
}
```

Comment: I'd initialize `myvar` to a string containing a number, e.g. `"0"`, otherwise he'll get a `NumberFormatException`. Also note that `y` doesn't have to be initialized, since it will be initialized by the assignments in the branches.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare variable outside if-else, right before.

`Double  y = 0;
if ()
 y =X;
else
 y =Y;`

Comment: `Double y=0` does not compile

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- You could declare it as a class member variable
- You could declare it within the scope of the method in which the `if/else` resides.

A couple of examples:

```
// as a member variable

public String myvar;
private Double y;

public void SomeMethod(int x)
{
    if(x > 5)
    {
        this.myvar = "0";
        this.y = Double.parseDouble(this.myvar);
        System.out.println("The value is: " + this.y);
    }
    else
    {
        this.y = Double.parseDouble(this.myvar);
        System.out.println("The value is: " + this.y);
    }

    // use this.y here
}
```

or

```
// as a method variable

public String myvar;

public void SomeMethod(int x)
{
    Double y;

    if(x > 5)
    {
        this.myvar = "0";
        y = Double.parseDouble(this.myvar);
        System.out.println("The value is: " + y);
    }
    else
    {
        y = Double.parseDouble(this.myvar);
        System.out.println("The value is: " + y);
    }

    // use y here
}
```